# What type of mic for use with vocals from an electric guitar amp?

Tags: microphones

I would like to purchase a microphone for use with a Roland 60 electric guitar amp. Does it have to be a dual impedance or do I need to purchase something to improve the volume level?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the AC-60? This has a mic/line input with phantom power so should work direct with most dynamic or condensor microphones. If  using a condensor mic, make sure it doesn't need more than 10mA current as this is the maximum it can provide according to the specs:

http://www.roland.co.uk/products/productdetails.aspx?p=559&c=739

Other than that you shouldn't need anything else - apart from a cable and a mic stand :-)